# Esconder divs quando o rato está fora?

Tags: html, jquery

Eu tenho um código assim estruturado

```
<?php 
$p=0;
$delay=0;
while($p<=16){ 
   $p++;
   $delay+=0.2;
   ?>
   <div class="column wow fadeInDown" onmouseout="outside(<?=$p; ?>)" onmouseover="inside(<?=$p; ?>)" data-detail="<?=$p; ?>" data-wow-delay="<?=$delay; ?>S">
      <div class="details detail<?=$p; ?>" style="">
          <div style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%,-50%);color:white;">
              <b>Nome do Produto</b>
          </div>
      </div>
   <img src="images/teste/<?=$p; ?>.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" />
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

No código acima tem uma galeria de imagens onde ao passar por cima mostraria o nome do produto. No entanto, quando passo por cima, ele mostra mas se passar para outro o anterior mantem-se. Como é que eu faço para esconder os outros e manter o mesmo?

Eis as funções `inside` e `outside`

```
function inside(e){
    $(".detail"+e).fadeIn(500);
}
function outside(e){
    $(".detail"+e).fadeOut(500);
}
```

Comment: não deveria tem um ponto "." antes de detail em `$("detail"+e).fadeOut(500);`?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Apenas um erro tipográfico, irei corrigir, mas mesmo normal não funciona

Comment: Cadê o estilo CSS do código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trabalhar com animações jQuery nesses casos é um pouco complicado porque a animação acontece de forma *assíncrona*. Quando você passa o rato em um elemento, sai e volta no mesmo instante, ocorre um *atropelo* porque a animação pode não ter terminado ainda e já dispara outra por cima, ocorrendo efeitos indesejáveis.

Sugiro fazer esse efeito usando apenas CSS com `transition` em `opacity` e `visibility` em conjunto. Desta forma o efeito é o mesmo e não ocorre problemas. Veja como ficaria o CSS:

```
.details{
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 0.5s;
}

.fadeInDown:hover .details{
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

E você não irá precisar dos eventos `onmouseover` e `onmouseout`.

Veja exemplo:

```css
*{
   position: relative
}

.details{
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 0.5s;
}

.fadeInDown:hover .details{
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="column wow fadeInDown" data-detail="1" data-wow-delay="<?=$delay; ?>S">
   <div  class="details detail1" style="">
       <div style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%,-50%);color:;">
           <b>Nome do Produto1</b>
       </div>
   </div>
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" style="max-width:20%;" />
</div>

<div class="column wow fadeInDown" data-detail="2" data-wow-delay="<?=$delay; ?>S">
   <div class="details detail2" style="">
       <div style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%,-50%);color:;">
           <b>Nome do Produto2</b>
       </div>
   </div>
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" style="max-width:20%;" />
</div>

<div class="column wow fadeInDown" data-detail="2" data-wow-delay="<?=$delay; ?>S">
   <div class="details detail3" style="">
       <div style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%,-50%);color:;">
           <b>Nome do Produto2</b>
       </div>
   </div>
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" style="max-width:20%;" />
</div>
```